# Marginalization of a paramter in Gaussian

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

If $\theta \sim N(\mu,\sigma_o^2)$ and $\mu \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)$ what is the marginalized $P(\theta)$.

Is it $N(0,\sigma_o^2+\sigma_1^2)$?

Answer (score 1):

It is often seen that someone writes things like "$\theta\sim N(\mu,\sigma_0^2)$ and $\mu\sim N(0,\sigma_1^2)$" when they ought to write "$\theta\mid\mu\sim N(\mu,\sigma_0^2)$ and $\mu\sim N(0,\sigma_1^2)$", i.e. the *conditional* distribution of $\theta$ given $\mu$ is that normal distribution.

Now think about the conditional distribution of $\theta-\mu$ given the value of $\mu$.  When we're conditioning on $\mu$, we treat $\mu$ as a constant, so we get $(\theta-\mu)\mid\mu \sim N(0,\sigma_0^2)$.  Now notice that the conditional distribution of $\theta-\mu$ given $\mu$ actually does not depend on $\mu$.  That implies that $\theta-\mu$ is independent of $\mu$.  It also implies that the marginal distribution of $\theta-\mu$ is the same as that conditional distribution.  So $\theta$ is the sum of two **independent** normally distibuted random variables, $\theta-\mu$ and $\mu$, and you know their distributions.  Now procede as you would whenever you want to know the distribution of the sum of two **independent** normally distibuted random variables whose distributions you know.